# Reverse NO limit switch signal

Tags: motor, switches, relay, normally-open

I am working on set a limit switch for safety function while moving a hoist. Due to the restriction of mechanical design, I can only choose the ball plunger limit switch (BP4SWA) which is Normally Open, but I do need to achieve a way that once the limit switch is closed, it would break out the power for moving the hoist up. Could I use a SPDT relay for reversing signal? I would be appreciated if someone could provide me suggestion on it, a simple electrical diagram would definitely help.

Comment: This is a very bad design decision. A safety function **must** have a forced disconnect when the unsafe condition occurs. The switch you have chosen has a 0.8 mm travel! If the contact breaks, a wire breaks or the signal inverting relay fails to pick up and open its NC contact them your safety function will fail. If it's a safety function then it needs a safety-rated switch. Be aware of your legal liability with your design decisions.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a SPDT relay will work.  I can't do a drawing right now.

Power the relay coil through the limit switch.

Run hoist power through the relay pole (armature) and the NC contact.  When the switch activates the relay, the NC contacts will open, removing power from the hoist.

Answer (score 0):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fpK4I0.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This is what @AnalogKid described.  V1 and V2 can be the same if your relay and load can run off the same voltage.  D1 part number 1N4001 is a placeholder and the actual part should be chosen based on your relay coil: voltage at least 2x the coil voltage, current greater than the normal coil current, fast Schottky type.

However, depending on how catastrophic the consequences of the limit switch not working are, you might want to add a bit onto the circuit to possibly include redundant limit switches and/or additional circuitry to disable the hoist if any connection on the coil side of the relay is broken.

Comment: Thank you for the information. I am wondering do I need additional latching circuit to hold power for moving the hoist when the switch is open?

Comment: You'll need your normal on/off switch to control the hoist; this is just the emergency cutoff.  When your limit switch is off/unactuated, the hoist will be controllable by a switch on the load side of the relay.